# Packaging multiple services into a war file for Java 8 in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine

In Google App Engine (GAE), you can package multiple services into a single exploded WAR file (a.k.a EAR file) but only if your app is running under Java 7. This does not work for Java 8:

> An App Engine application that uses services is organized as an
>   unpacked Java Enterprise Archive (EAR) directory structure. The
>   top-level EAR directory contains a single META-INF subdirectory, and a
>   separate directory for each service in the app. Note that EAR is
>   supported for the Java 7 runtime only, not for the Java 8 runtime.

I couldn't find anything in the GAE docs that indicates how you package multiple services into a single WAR file.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/configuration-files

I realize that I can create a separate WAR file for each service but the local dev server supplied by Google for testing your app only accepts a single WAR file. I could run multiple instances of the dev server using different ports but that seems kind of messy.

Comment: The devappserver provided with the Cloud SDK does support running multiple services, and this is supported by Cloud Tools for Eclipse.  You do have to deploy the services individually however.

Answer (score 1):

Google does have a solution but they documented in the most obscure location:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/migrate-gradle

It was easy to overlook this because the title of the document is:

> Migrating to the Cloud SDK-based Gradle plugin

If you are building an app from scratch, you are not migrating anything and would easily skip this documentation. It should really have been documented at:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/gradle

Some additional instructions can be found at:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-gradle-plugin/blob/master/USER_GUIDE.md