# Services in GAE Java 8 standard environment

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, gae-eclipse-plugin

I would like to know if there is any way to create a multiple services app in GAE using the Java 8 standard runtime environment.

I am using Eclipse and it looks forbidden to include the WAR in an EAR structure when creating a Dynamic Web Project under this environment.

Sounds logical regarding : https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/configuration-files#the_default_service

> An App Engine application that uses services is organized as an
>   unpacked Java Enterprise Archive (EAR) directory structure. The
>   top-level EAR directory contains a single META-INF subdirectory, and a
>   separate directory for each service in the app. Note that EAR is
>   supported for the Java 7 runtime only, not for the Java 8 runtime.

Is there any way to bypass the EAR structure for ex ? or any other suggestion ?
Worst case, does anybody know if there is anything planned to support the services structure anytime soon ?

Comment: maybe of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48805469/packaging-multiple-services-into-a-war-file-for-java-8-in-gae

Comment: sounds like it, will try the Gradle thing, sry for the almost duplicate topic and thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Tools for Eclipse does support multiple services: select the corresponding projects, right-click and *Debug As > App Engine*.  Or add the projects to an existing App Engine dev server definition in the *Servers* view.  Deployment currently must be done one at a time; please provide your feedback to https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-eclipse/issues/2625.

Comment: Did not like the Gradle thing, too heavy for my project, have reverted to a simple web project in between... Just launching 2 projects on same dev server seems to work at least, will let you know if I try & split my project again...